Where does Spyder save files that were changed?
In Spyder I have a checkmark on Preferences - Editor - Advanced Settings - Automatically save a copy of file with unsaved changes (Autosave interval 60 sec).
But where I could find the saved file?
Spyder version: 5.5.1
I read some threads here concerning this problem, but didn't find the answer.

Are you on Windows? Linux?

Related, possible duplicate: How to recover unsaved file in spyder (see this answer for Linux and this answer for Windows, specifically)

@TylerH Thanks. I am on Windows. My autosave directory is empty((
